# RAID on VMware, Ubuntu guest

Tags: ubuntu, raid, virtual-machines, vmware-server

I am doing some local testing on VMware server. I have set up my VM with two hard drives. I am installing Ubuntu Server, and creating manually in the installation the luks above a RAID 1 configuration. My question is: Should I locate each virtual hard drive in a different physical drive to take advantage of RAID?  Otherwise, if they both are in the same drive, I see no actual point of having a RAID.

In any case, I know this is not a "desirable" configuration, and it would probably better to have a hardware RAID controller (like in a PowerDell f. ex.) and have the VMs inside without knowing about the RAID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I locate each virtual hard drive in a different physical drive
>   to take advantage of RAID?

Erm...yes, anything else would be a waste of time/space as you say, and yes a HW controller would be better.